# list all facebook friend requests

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to list all friendship requests using the facebook graph API? I didn't find anything in the docs, but with the experience I've undergone concerning the quality of this doc so far, I wouldn't be surprised if there was a way to it.

Comment: Now you can use `/me/friendrequests` to get friend requests provided that you have sufficient permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's not possible using only Graph API. You will need to use any SDK and then make a FQL query.

Here you go:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend_request/